# How to write htaccess to redirect my site?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I use SMF to running my forum.

This is old forum URL => **hxxp://www.example.com/**

But now, I move my forum to "forum" folder => **hxxp://www.example.com/forum/**

Google and other search engine indexed my site with url: **hxxp://www.example.com/index.php?topic=99.0**

And when users go to **hxxp://www.example.com/index.php?topic=99.0**, It's not found.

Because he must to go to **hxxp://www.example.com/forum/index.php?topic=99.0**, right?

So, I want to redirect url 
   from **hxxp://www.example.com/index.php?topic=99.0**
   to **hxxp://www.example.com/forum/index.php?topic=99.0**

How should I do? I try this but not work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php?topic=([0-9]+).([0-9]+)$ forum/index.php?topic=$1.$2 [R]
```

Comment: Try `^/index.php` instead of `^index.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on where you put htaccess. If it is in /forum/ then

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/forum\/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/forum/index.php [R]
```

AFAIK query string is not affected by RewriteRule regexp.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must escape the dot (`.`) metacharacter in the RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php?topic=([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)$ /forum/index.php?topic=$1.$2 [R]
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will help  u

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]
RewriteRule ^index.php?topic([=0-9.]+)$  old/index.php?topic=$1 [QSA,L]
```